# FinAll in MongoDb using Spring return only one record

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

the problem is once i  use method findAll using MongoOperation interface, it working fine with no exception but only return One Record, however the collection contain more than 1 record. i tried a different interface like mongotemp and also the same result, List size is return always 1, even when i try it from dao itself

---

Configuration Spring DATA with mongodb

```
@Configuration
public class MongodbConfig {

public @Bean MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "inSpace");
}

public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    return mongoTemplate;

}
}
```

---

DAO Class

```
@Repository
public class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T>  {

@Autowired
protected MongoOperations mongoOper;

public <T> void save(T ct) {
    mongoOper.save(ct);
}

public <T> void remove(T ct) {
    mongoOper.remove(ct);
}

public T getBydId(String id, Class<T> clazz) {
    return mongoOper.findById(id, clazz);
}

public List<T> getAll(Class<T> clazz) {
    System.err.println(" '''''''  " + mongoOper.findAll(clazz).size());
    return mongoOper.findAll(clazz);
}

}
```

Note: the upper two classs in a single project and used as dependency for the other project who contain the below classes

---

Service calling DAO

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private  GenericDAO<Users> userDAO;

public Users create(Users user) {
    userDAO.save(user);
    return user;
}

public Users delete(String id) {
    Users user = userDAO.getBydId(id, Users.class);
    userDAO.remove(user);
    return user;
}

public List<Users> findAll() {
    System.out.println("inside User Service");
    return userDAO.getAll(Users.class);
}

public Users findById(String id) {
    return userDAO.getBydId(id , Users.class);
}
```

### }

Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user") 
public class UsersController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/allUsers")
List<Users> getAllRegistedUsers() {
    System.out.println("inside  UserController");
    return userService.findAll();
}
```

### }

Configuration Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses=
{UsersController.class,UserService.class,GenericDAO.class})
public class UsersConfiguration {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(UsersConfiguration.class, args);

}
```

### }

Note: when i try to inject bean in Main methods and use the bean by ApplicationContext it's work fine and return all records in database !?

Comment: Why are you not using org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository?

Comment: @notionquest also i tried this one and try crudRepo. and it's the same result i don't know where is the issue